# Customizing UITableViewCell IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, background-color

This currently what my cell looks like: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=344uz2a&s=6

As can be seen, for some reason it refuses to fill the right part of the cell with backgroundColor white. And I have no clue why or what the problem may be?

This is how I have implemented my TableView / Cells. In viewDidLoad i set the entire tableView to clearColor to hide "emptyCells".

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

 self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
 tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

In the method below I try to set the cells backgroundColor. Unfortunately as described above it refuses to set the whiteColor to the right, in the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)pTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SearchCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [pTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
Task *task = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *bookLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
UILabel *chapterLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];

[nameLabel setText:task.name];
[bookLabel setText:task.book.name];
[chapterLabel setText:task.chapter.name];

cell.backgroundColor =  [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor =  [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

return cell;
}
```

Any ideas? What have I missed or what can I do to solve this "color" issue? Thanx in regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks you need to set the background color of the accessory view as well like so:

```
self.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

If you look inspect the bounds for the background view it probably does not span the entire table cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

or

```
cell.backgroundView.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```